# Is it true that $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = n(\mathbb{S}^{1})^{d}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I know that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{S}^{1}$ is the unit sphere and also $\mathbb{R}^{d}/\mathbb{Z}^{d} \cong (\mathbb{S}^{1})^{d}$. But given a positive integer $n$, is it true that $\mathbb{R}/n\mathbb{Z} = n\mathbb{S}^{1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = n(\mathbb{S}^{1})^{d}$? In loose terms, should $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ be treated like $[0,n)^{d}$? If so, how to address this problem to prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by $n\Bbb{S}^1$? There are contexts (cobordism theory) where multiplying a space by a natural number makes sense. Treating $[0, n)^d$ as $\Bbb{R}^d/n\Bbb{Z}^d$ sounds dangerous to me: there is an obvious identification of the sets, but the topology is very different.

Comment: What is $n S^1$ ? In fact the natural maps (not only one) between $\Bbb{R^d/a Z^d}$ and $\Bbb{R^d/b Z^d}$ (for integers $a,b$ or real numbers or invertible matrices) is more interesting than the relation you are thinking to which is more a matter of definition than anything else.

Comment: Imagine you wind the real line into the coil, each perimeter of circles is 1. This is the picture of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. (You can look the coil from $z$-axis so you see just the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$.) $\mathbb{R}/n\mathbb{Z}$ situation is the same situation with perimeters $n$, not 1. it is still circle, and the topology of the circle $\mathbb{R}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is exactly the same with the circle $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. Let me clarify the points you raised. Actually, I'm new to algebra so my post might contain some mistakes. I'd like to have a better picture of what $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ is. I'm only interested in the algebraic properties of $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ and how to picture it in my mind. I think the correct statement would be $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = \{[x]: \hspace{0.1cm} x \in [0,n)\}^{d}$? Is it true? And how to prove it?

Comment: Also, by $n\mathbb{S}^{1}$ I mean $\{nx: \hspace{0.1cm} x \in \mathbb{S}^{1}\}$.

Comment: So, for example, $(1,0) \in S^1$ and $n(1,0)=(n,0) \in n \mathbb S^1$? If that's the case, I would next wonder what is the group operation on $n\mathbb S^1$...